# Java Window Application

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, windows

I am working on a project in which I am creating a window based application for annotation of pdf documents in java eclipse IDE. I am not getting how to display a pdf file in java windows application. Is it possible to display pdf in the windows and then underline or add comments to it for annotation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you explain more, what you have done, piece of sample code and what are your problems so I can help you...!

Comment: what you are using for developing eg. swing or javaFX

Comment: I am using swing, I want that when the browse button is clicked any pdf file can be chosen and displayed in the java window itself.